# Need to rewrite a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a Cursor and looking to remove the stored procedure and use a set-based operation or any other methods or suggestions.

Possible Fixes:

1. Add the FOR clause to the existing stored proc (Create_Sales_Orders)
2. Add a While Loop

   ```
   WHILE @currentRow<=@rowCount
   BEGIN
       -- EXEC Create_Sales_Orders

       SET  @currentRow = @currentRow + 1
   END
   ```

My Cursor

```
DECLARE MyCNT CURSOR FOR

        ................

        -- Select statement Returns 6 columns and 69 rows of data

        ................
    OPEN MyCNT
          FETCH NEXT FROM MyCNT INTO @StoreId,@DateToProcess,@Cus_source_id,@Cus_id,@Pos_Source_id,@POS_Id 
               WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
                   BEGIN

                       EXEC Create_Sales_Orders   --> looking to get rid of this....take a long time to run
                            @StoreId, 
                            @DateToProcess,
                            @Cus_source_id,
                            @Cus_id,
                            @Pos_Source_id,
                            @POS_Id    


                   FETCH NEXT FROM MyCNT INTO @StoreId,@DateToProcess,@Cus_source_id,@Cus_id,@Pos_Source_id,@POS_Id 
               END
    CLOSE MyCNT
    DEALLOCATE MyCNT
```

Comment: What does `Create_Sales_Orders` do?

Comment: Calls a series of inserts and updates to a sales transaction table....

Comment: So you want to rewrite your SP to be faster?

Comment: What do you want to replace the stored procedure with? Insert the logic of the procedure into the body of your cursor? Eliminate the cursor altogether & use a set-based operation? What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: It would be better to post the source code for Create_Sales_Orders, maybe there is a way to perform all operations in a "set-based" manner. If the code in Create_Sales_Orders is too complex, I don't see a way to rewrite the cursor, or at least I don't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @DanielE. be careful with `MERGE` it has some [well documented bugs](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: The source code is complex and proprietary business rules and logic...I'm going to rewrite `Create_Sales_Orders` to be faster

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck with row-by-row processing, at least without a fully inlining the Create_Sales_Orders body into main query, but it don't seem like an easy job ("Calls a series of inserts and updates").

No use replacing cursor with any other loop, just use `FAST_FORWARD` cursor and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to rewrite Create_Sales_Orders to be faster